# Signing data in c++ app using CNG and verifying in php api

Tags: php, c++, winapi, public-key-encryption, cng

I read a lot about asymmetric encryption and still can't understand how is the step by step process to achieve what I need.

**What I need:**

1. Create 1 Private and 1 Public key only once.
2. Include the private key in my C++ app without the user being able to read it (ofc everything can be hacked, but you know what I mean, don't let the user see it in plain text).
3. Distribute the app.
4. Then my app, when used, will Hash an string.
5. Encrypt this hash with the included private key.
6. Send this signed hash to my api using an http request.
7. Decrypt the signed hash in my api (php) using my Public Key.

**What I don't understand:**

Using the example here: [Signing Data with CNG](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/desktop/SecCNG/signing-data-with-cng#signing-and-verifying-data-example) I don't get how can I create the keys once then store the private one in my c++ app and the public one in my api (php).

**What I achieved**

I learned to hash and encrypt/decrypt data using bCrypt but I don't understand what steps I have to do to achieve what I wrote before

Comment: Well, why don't you pre-create the keys, store the modulus/exponent or PEM or other format for the private key in a safe place in your app (obfuscated memory, ...) and then by using `BCryptImportKeyPair` you will have the key in your C++ app.

Comment: Because this is the exact part that I don't understand. How can I create the key pair then save it to a file and include the private key on the c++ app and the public on my php api.

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly is hard for you? I mean to generate keys - there are online rsa key generation tools, openssl comand line tools, etc. There are well defined formats for storage like PEM, X.509,... And as you already showed in the question, there are MSDN and non MSDN BCrypt examples. I do not think that anyone is gonna do the whole work for you, but if you specify the problematic parts, it is much easier to help.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't at the pc until now. My problem comes when I read Key Provider and Key Storage Provider. I mean I still don't get how is the process to create a key, is it like "CreateKeyPair("random_value", "data\key.extension)" and it outputs a key pair in a file (CreateKeyPair being a function that does all the dllcalls needed to create the keypair)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the design. Currently you design has a major security flaw. You got the concepts of the pubkey/prikey correct, but the implementation is incorrect. The private key should be kept private. Currently it is easy to derive the public key, given the private key for a lot of algorithms, but not the other way around. The right design is as follows.

1. Generate a self-signed certificate. This certificate will contain private and public key
2. Export the public certificate and embed it as resource/or hardcode it in your application that you are going to distribute
3. The application will then hash the data to be signed and use the public key from the application resource.
4. This hashed data is then sent over the http to your server that has the copy of private key.
5. The server will hash the data and verify the hash with the private key.

All of the above steps are well documented with samples on MSDN. If you need further help, let me know and I can point it to the articles.

The above design will make sure that your private key is never in the wild. If you distribute your private key in your application, it will take literally only few minutes to get your private key.

Storing the public key in the application is just the matter of either hardcoding the key in the application using byte array or putting the certificate in the resource file.

The private key portion of the key pair should never be hardcoded in any application. The private key should be non exportable and be managed by the operating system only. Windows now has keyguard that uses VSM technology that makes it impossible for even the local administrator to know the private key. The admin can only use it for signing and verifying (and exporting the key, if exporting is enabled) but never be able to look at the private key and misuse it.

Regarding step by step process.

1. Create a self-signed certificate. This will generate a certificate with both public and private key in the pfx file.
2. Import the self-signed certificate in the certificate store. This can be achived by simply double-clicking on the file and following the directions.
3. Export the public portion of newly imported certificate from by opening the certificate manager.
4. You can embed this public exported certificate in your application as a resource.
5. The application can then load the certificate from the resource and use it to sign the hash.
6. On the server side, if the certificate with private key is not already imported, follow the step 2 to import it.
7. Server can then use the Apis to verify the signed data using private key.

Comment: Actually I need to sign the data that comes FROM the app, not from the server.

Comment: Not sure why you would need to sign the data sent by something that is untrusted and could be easily hacked. You will still need to reexamine the scenario if that is what makes sense.

Considering the fact that you cannot and should not embed a private key in an application this is the solution that you can use.

1. The application user needs to sign on to your server using some form or authentication (username/password) that is not embedded/hardcoded in your application.
2. The server can then issue a certificate for the user that the application will store it in a secured manner...

Comment: In windows that would the certificate store. The step 1 & 2 needs to be done only once.

3. The application can then user the private key of the certificate to sign the data which the server will verify using public key since the server is the one that issued the certificate to the user. The server does not store the private key, it stores only public key.


Essentially, what you are trying to do is skip step 1 somehow by storing the private key in the application. Remember that storing the private key in the application is like storing the password in the application.

Comment: Would you use an application that stores the password of your facebook/gmail/etc in your application?

Comment: I understand that part. I need to sign the data that comes from my app. If the protection in the exe is broken it doesn't matter if they can read the private key because they have already "opened" the exe.
If I don't have a private key in the exe then every data that comes from it can be easily manipulated before it's sent to my server. I need to be sure that the data was generated by my app.

Comment: Also, including the private key is not that risky since it only allows the user to manipulate the data sent to the server the same way they could if my client didn't use a private key. So adding a private key is adding another layer of protection.

Comment: quoting you "I need to be sure that the data was generated by my app."    You will never ever be sure of that if you include the private key in your app. One day you will be sitting and having coffee and wondering if the data received by your server is really something that your app generated and you will come back and read my messages and think of how much room for improvement your design had. Good luck.

Comment: You do not seem to undestand what I'm trying to do, thanks anyway for the answers.

Comment: Oh I understand what you are trying to do. It is because of fundamentally flawed and vulnerable software design like yours is why I have my job security. :-)